# java - How to load images in memory from a domain file system?

Tags: java

I want to make an app that displays different images. I have those images stored on my domain. Like any domain it has a file system where i can upload different images . What i want to do is to access those images from there and to load them in memory at runtime. Is that posible or do i need to make a file transfer through a java program and store them localy and load them after in memory ? Or is there a better strategy in doing this ?

P.S: I was thinking about loading those images in a MySQL Database but as i searched i found out that it`s not recommended to do that because they are saved as large binary files and its quite expensive (as database memory gets huge and performance is lowered).

Comment: I'm assuming you want other clients to download the images? In that case, I'd be simpler to leave the on the disk a simply write the stream to the client on request. Personally I'd avoid loading them into memory, as they will consume much of the memory really quickly

Comment: HTML documents are designed to be streamed from disk and memory - your webserver and its configuration should take care of caching. All you need to do is configure your webserver accordingly. After that, you ma generate HTTP requests on your clients each time - and dont worry about efficiency anymore.